# Can't request for certificate form agent using ' puppet agent --test '

Tags: ssl-certificate, puppet

[image]

I am new to puppet, I am configuring connecting between puppet master "puppet" I have edited the host file on agent & client as well as I have edited the puppet.conf on agent node to resolve the master. I can ping in between both servers.

I checked on master for cert list but there were no requests.

But still I am getting this error.

How can fix this?

My configuration is :

Puppet master is :

Name: puppet, Agent: centos

Both are on VM, both have same puppet version

Comment: What command are you running  and what error are you getting ?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: I am running 'puppet agent --test' from agent node to generate a certificate on a master server so that master server can sign the certificate.
But some how the agent is not able to request the puppet server.
I have proper communication between both of them.

Comment: Error I'm getting is :

[root@centos ~]# puppet agent --test
Error: Could not request certificate: Connection refused - connect(2) for "puppet" port 8140
Exiting; failed to retrieve certificate and waitforcert is disabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Issue was in new version of puppet we have to run enable the puppet server. Only starting the puppet server & services will not work we have to enable the server as well. 
Following command is for starting the server :

> puppet resource service puppetserver ensure=running

This command is to enable the server.

> puppet resource service puppetserver enable=true

Comment: Did you run this on master or host? I have ensure=present inside /manifests/init.pp. Is it the same?

Comment: i tried this but it still gives the same error. any alternative solution? cause of this error?

Answer (score 2):

In `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf`

`server = SERVER_FQDN`

Try giving the ip address here.

Comment: Use autosign feature in server or request the certificate with the waitforcert option enabled

Answer (score 0):

To start putty on master machine below mentioned command doesn't work in newer puppet versions

```
systemctl status puppetserver
```

To start the puppet master you need to start the server and enable the server

**Command is for starting the server**:

```
puppet resource service puppetserver ensure=running
```

**Command is to enable the server**:

```
puppet resource service puppetserver enable=true
```

And on slave machine below command to start puppet

```
systemctl status puppetserver
```

Answer (score -1):

You have configured in the agent (puppet.conf) the master hostname, "puppet":

1. Add it to the /etc/hosts in the agent server. A row indicating the master IP and hostname is needed.
2. Then, execute sudo puppet cert sign --all in your master.